How do I efficiently generate, store and read in Gaunt(-like) coefficients from a file?
I'm calculating the mode-mixing between various spin-weighted spherical harmonics (SWSHs) $_sY_{l}^{m}(\theta,\varphi)$. In what follows the indices can take the following values, $l_{max}$ being some universal cut-off (say 15) :
$$s = -2,\,..\,,2 \quad\quad l =|s|, \,.., l_{max} \quad \quad m = -l,\; .. l$$
Given that the product of two SWSHs can be expanded into a linear combination of different SWSHs
$$\begin{aligned}
{ }_{s_1} Y_{\ell_1}{ }^{m_1}{ }_{s_2} Y_{\ell_2}{ }^{m_2}= & \sum_{\ell_3=\left|\ell_1-\ell_2\right|}^{\ell_1+\ell_2}(-1)^{s_1+s_2+m_1+m_2} 
 \times{ } \;\;\;_{s_1 s_2-\left(s_1+s_2\right)} G_{\ell_1}{ }^{m_1}{ }_{\ell_2}{ }^{m_2}{ }_{\ell_3}{ }^{-\left(m_1+m_2\right)}{ }_{s_1+s_2} Y_{\ell_3}{ }^{m_1+m_2}
\end{aligned}$$
where the Gaunct coefficients $G$ are defined via the Wigner 3-j symbols
$$\begin{aligned}
 _{s_1 s_2 s_3}
 G_{\ell_1}{ }^{m_1}{ }_{\ell_2}{ }^{m_2}{ }_{\ell_3}{ }^{m_3}= \sqrt{\frac{\left(2 \ell_1+1\right)\left(2 \ell_2+1\right)\left(2 \ell_3+1\right)}{4 \pi}} 
 \times\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\ell_1 & \ell_2 & \ell_3 \\
-s_1 & -s_2 & -s_3
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\ell_1 & \ell_2 & \ell_3 \\
m_1 & m_2 & m_3
\end{array}\right) .
\end{aligned}$$
In other words, to coefficient of $_{s}Y_l^m$ in the expansion of ${ }_{s_1} Y_{\ell_1}{ }^{m_1}{ }_{s_2} Y_{\ell_2}{ }^{m_2}$ can be written as
$$_{s}\Big[{ }_{s_1} Y_{\ell_1}{ }^{m_1}{ }_{s_2} Y_{\ell_2}{ }^{m_2}\Big]_l^{\;\;m} = \delta_{m,m_1+m2} \;\;\delta_{s,s_1+s_2} \;\;(-1)^{s_1+s_2+m_1+m_2} \;\;\; _{s_1 s_2-\left(s_1+s_2\right)} G_{\ell_1}{ }^{m_1}{ }_{\ell_2}{ }^{m_2}{ }_{\ell_3}{ }^{-\left(m_1+m_2\right)}$$
What I'm doing is the natural extention of this to a product of 5 SWSHs, which in vague terms is the following:
$$
_{s}\Big[\prod_{i =1}^5\;\;{ }_{s_i} Y_{\ell_i}{ }^{m_i}\Big]_l^{\;\;m} \sim \sum_. \sum_.\sum_.\; _{...} G_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.} \; _{...} G_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.} \; _{...} G_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.}  \; _{...} G_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.}{ }_{.}{ }^{.} 
$$
I call the resulting number penta, it is generically a function of all the $(s,l,m),\{ s_i,l_i,m_i\}_{i=1..5} $ numbers,
penta[{ss_, ll_, mm_}, {s1_, l1_, m1_}, {s2_, l2_, m2_}, {s3_, l3_, m3_}, \
{s4_, l4_, m4_}, {s5_, l5_, m5_}]

My question is: how do I pre-generate and store these value of penta in a file that I can read in whenever I need, potentially across multiple notebooks? Calculating them on-the-fly is not feasible (even if I memoize penta), it just takes too long.
Since the 5-fold product of SWSHs is trivially invariant under permutations of the 5 $(s_i,l_i,m_i)$ triplets, it should be enough to store penta for only a "canonically" ordered version of the $\{ s_i,l_i,m_i\}_{i=1..5}$ sector, using e.g. LexicographicSort.
Here's a rudimentary way to calculate penta, without the aformentioned ordering scheme:
GauntCV2[s1_, s2_, s3_, l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_, l3_, m3_] := 
  If[m1 + m2 + m3 == 0 && s1 + s2 + s3 == 0, 
   Sqrt[((2 l1 + 1) (2 l2 + 1) (2 l3 + 
          1))/(4 Pi)] ThreeJSymbol[{l1, -s1}, {l2, -s2}, {l3, -s3}] \
ThreeJSymbol[{l1, m1}, {l2, m2}, {l3, m3}], 0];

tmpGauntCV2[s1_, s2_, l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_, l3_] := 
  GauntCV2[s1, s2, -(s1 + s2), l1, m1, l2, m2, l3, -(m1 + m2)];

Penta[{ss_, ll_, mm_}, {s1_, l1_, m1_}, {s2_, l2_, m2_}, {s3_, l3_, 
   m3_}, {s4_, l4_, m4_}, {s5_, l5_, m5_}] := 
 KroneckerDelta[ss, s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5]*
  KroneckerDelta[mm, m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5] Simplify@
   Sum[(-1)^(s1 + s2 + m1 + m2) tmpGauntCV2[s1, s2, l1, m1, l2, m2, 
      lp]*tmpGauntCV2[s4, s3, l4, m4, l3, m3, lpp]*
     tmpGauntCV2[s5, s1 + s2, l5, m5, lp, m1 + m2, lppp]*
     tmpGauntCV2[s1 + s2 + s5, s3 + s4, lppp, m1 + m2 + m5, lpp, 
      m3 + m4, ll], {lp, Abs[l1 - l2], l1 + l2}, {lpp, Abs[l3 - l4], 
     l3 + l4}, {lppp, Abs[l5 - lp], l5 + lp}]

Quiet@Penta[{-3, 12, 7}, {1, 1, 0}, {-2, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 2}, {-1, 2, 
   2}, {-1, 2, 2}]
(* 315/(2024 Sqrt[323] \[Pi]^2)*)

